# jQuery / AJAX - refresh <div> on success - not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am unable (for whatever reason) to populate my `<div id="Last20Requests"></div>` tag with data obtained from my AJAX query, even though the query was successful and data is shown in the console log. I have tried multiple ways to populate the  including `load`, `append`, `prepend`, etc, all to no avail.
My last attempt was to add an alert box in case the load was successful, but naturally it doesnt show up in the first place.

I dont think that anything is wrong my `<div>`, but I would appreciate help on that mystery please.

```
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">20 Last Requests</h3><div class="text small pull-right">Refresh</div>
      </div>
      <!-- /. box-header -->
      <div class="box-body">
        <div id="Last20Requests" name="Last20Requests"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box -->

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">           
    $(function() {
        var prevAjaxReturned = true;
        var xhr = null;

        setInterval(function() {
            if( prevAjaxReturned ) {
                prevAjaxReturned = false;
            } else if( xhr ) {
                xhr.abort( );
            }

            xhr = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../../plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php',
                data: {
                    action: 'refresh_rescap_reqs',
                    holidex: '<?php echo($_SESSION['Holidex']); ?>',
                    access: '<?php echo $_SESSION['Access']; ?>'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                     // data is a string of all output of the server script.
                    //$('#Last20Requests').html(data);
                    //$("#Last20Requests").html(data);
                    //$.find("#Last20Requests").html(data);
                    //$("#Last20Requests").load(JSON.stringify(data));
                    //$("#Last20Requests").load(data);
                    //$("#Last20Requests").append(data);
                    $("#Last20Requests").load(data, function() {
                      alert( "Load was performed." );
                    });
                    prevAjaxReturned = true;
               },
            });

        }, 5000);   // 1000ms = 1 sec
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: `$('#Last20Requests').html(data);` or `$("#Last20Requests").html(data);` this should simply work, check console for more erros

Comment: put an alert just after success function and check your `success` is being hit or not? for more on this check your console as well for any errors

Comment: tried that, but no result. Console is clear, XHR have the proper result, no error there.

Comment: The name attribute doesn't exist for a DIV. Maybe when you take it away all will work well.
<div id="Last20Requests" name="Last20Requests"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `dataType: 'json'` because you result is `HTML` not `JSON` :

```
xhr = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../../plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php',
                data: {
                    action: 'refresh_rescap_reqs',
                    holidex: '<?php echo($_SESSION['Holidex']); ?>',
                    access: '<?php echo $_SESSION['Access']; ?>'
                },
                //dataType: 'json', //remove this line
                success: function(data) {
                     // data is a string of all output of the server script.
                    //$('#Last20Requests').html(data);
                    //$("#Last20Requests").html(data);
                    //$.find("#Last20Requests").html(data);
                    //$("#Last20Requests").load(JSON.stringify(data));
                    //$("#Last20Requests").load(data);
                    //$("#Last20Requests").append(data);
                    $("#Last20Requests").load(data, function() {
                      alert( "Load was performed." );
                    });
                    prevAjaxReturned = true;
               },
            });
```

Comment: Winner ;) Thanks a lot. Bonus question though: how can I run the ajax call immediately on page load and after that every 5 seconds? Right now the page loads and then after 5 secs loads for the first time.

Comment: put the code "xhr = $.ajax ..." in a function and call it in $(document).ready(function () { ajaxFunction(); } and call the some function in the setInterval()